# reg expression of number of duplicated numbers

Tags: regex

I have following question need reg expert help. I have a string "11122233344456", I need put same digits into a string. For above example, it shall be "111","222","333","444","5","6".

Another example: "223334456111", it shall be "22","333","44","5","6","111".

Would some regex expert help me to find the solution?

Comment: Why a regexp here? I think a simple loop would to this task faster.

Comment: what language are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
((\d)\2*)
```

And grab captured group #1

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/uI2rJ6/1)